# Populate fields not displayed on page with JS

Tags: javascript, fields

I've got some script which uses Postcode Anywhere's functionality to retrieve an addresses latitude and longitude and stores them in Lat__c and Long__c custom fields.  The fields are not displayed on the page and the JS works by querying the record and applying the values to the returned result.  This works fine for editing existing records, but if we're on the New page, there is no record to query therefore it doesn't work.

So my question - using only JS (and I can't use merge fields because this is not written on the platform, but I can use functionality provided by /soap/ajax/30.0/connection.js) how can I populate values in fields which are not displayed on the page?

I'm hoping there's some way I can just inject the fields into the form with the values in, and the values will be applied to the database when I press save.  Is that possible?  Alternatively, is it possible to add them to POST?

Thanks

EDIT I wanted to add that I've tried dynamically creating form elements and adding them inside the standard edit form.  Although they appear, and contain the correct values, when I press save the values are not applied :(

```
var inpt=document.createElement("input");
inpt.type = "text";
inpt.value = "1";
inpt.setAttribute("id", "00Ne0000000pKuy");
inpt.setAttribute("name", "00Ne0000000pKuy");

document.getElementById("editPage").appendChild(inpt);

var inpt2=document.createElement("input");
inpt2.type = "text";
inpt2.value = "2";
inpt2.setAttribute("id", "00Ne0000000pKuz");
inpt2.setAttribute("name", "00Ne0000000pKuz");

document.getElementById("editPage").appendChild(inpt2);
```

Comment: Are you using this in a VF page ?

Comment: No its on standard pages.  Postcode anywhere picks up when the user selects an address and allows you to run some Javascript.